# Issue with Typescript Array & ChartJs

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, charts, angular7

I'm trying to use `ChartJs` with angular7 and I have to show some simple data in a Pie Chart.

According documentation I only need to populate an array and pass it to the canvass component. But when I generate the array inside a loop (using method push, because I get the data from a server, o this array has dynamic length) something goes wrong and the pie shows the data only in grey, while it should pick random colors for every couple value/label.

But if a build the array like in the doc `[a,b,c,d]`, they are showed correctly.

--Wrong Array

```
this.pieChartLabels = [];
this.pieChartData = [];
for (const x of this.userWorkloadArray) {
  this.pieChartData.push(2);
  this.pieChartLabels.push(x.username);
}
```

[image: wrong visualization]

--Correct array

```
this.pieChartLabels = [['Download', 'Sales'], ['In', 'Store', 'Sales'], 'Mail Sales'];

this.pieChartData = [300, 500, 100];
```

[image: correct visualization]

Comment: You are probably creating the Pie chart before the data has actually loaded. You have to wait for the data to return using `await` or `.then()`, depending on how you fetch the data.

Comment: I create the pie before having data because my array is dynamic and initially it has length = 0

Comment: OK, but then you’ll have to update the pie chart once you have received the data.